# Is JConsole CPU usage only for the Java process?

Tags: java, cpu, jconsole

I want to know if the cpu usage data in jconsole is for the entire server or just the java process which the JConsole is monitoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jconsole or jvisualvm instrument the Java virtual machine to get the performance and resource consumption/utilization of a process. Its  a tool for monitoring  Java virtual machine, i think this gives details of JVM irrespective of number of apps/server deployed in it